# Make field content as exposed filter dropdown

Tags: 7, views

I have a field in my node like brand, where in admin enters the brand name and creates the node. I want to make a exposed filter out of this as a dropdown with all the data entered by the admin. How do i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question isn't 100% clear but it sounds like you want to display the nodes in a view and want to filter them with an exposed "brand" dropdown? 
I also assume your "brand" field is a term reference to a vocabulary.

Create a view for the nodes and add a filter for "Content: Has taxonomy term" and select your "brand" vocabulary, "dropdown" as the filter type and "expose this filter".

Comment: Nope its not a term reference. Its just a text box where admin enters brand names like nokia and in another node samsung. So i want to make dropdown of all these values entered and avoid duplicates also.

Comment: you still take the same steps, just select that "brand" field as the filter and expose it. There is an option to not show duplicate values

Comment: BUt its coming as a textbox exposed filter rather then dropdown..